# How to add serializer in the services xml file?

Tags: symfony4, shopware

I am trying to use `Serializer` Component in `shopware 6` I have create a Serializer Class which I want to inject as DI in the controller.

### Serializer.php

```
class Serializer
{
    public function getSerializer(): Serializer
    {
        $encoder = [new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizer = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

        return new Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);
    }

}
```

### MyController.php

```
public function __construct(Serializer $serializer)
{
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
}
```

My problem is how to include this serializer in my `services.xml` file

```
<service id="SwagMasterApi\Core\Api\MyController" public="true">

            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
<service>
```

Can anybody help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your Serializer as a service and inject it as an argument to Controller. For instance, if FQCN of your serializer is `SwagMasterApi\Service\Serializer`. You need to add the following code into your services.xml

```
<service id="SwagMasterApi\Service\Serializer">
<service>

<service id="SwagMasterApi\Core\Api\MyController" public="true">
    <argument type="service" id="SwagMasterApi\Service\Serializer" />
<service>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just passing argument inside service (last 3 steps of your solution). I didn't knew I need to define service first. Thanks once again.

Comment: You are welcome. Until your service does not have any arguments you can skip it and your service (class) will be autowired.